# I just used maplibre native and encountered a problem while using node example

Tags: node.js, maplibre-gl

Firstly, I installed various environments and then ran this example. The code is as follows, and the problem occurred

```
// var mbgl = require('@maplibre/maplibre-gl-native');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mbgl = require('../../lib/node-v' + process.versions.modules + '/mbgl');
// var mbgl = require('@maplibre/maplibre-gl-native');
var sharp = require('sharp');

var options = {
  request: function(req, callback) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test', req.url), function(err, data) {
      callback(err, { data: data });
    });
  },
  ratio: 1
};

var map = new mbgl.Map(options);

map.load(require('./test/fixtures/style.json'));

map.render({zoom: 0}, function(err, buffer) {
    if (err) throw err;
    map.release();
    var image = sharp(buffer, {
        raw: {
            width: 512,
            height: 512,
            channels: 4
        }
    });

    // Convert raw image buffer to PNG
    image.toFile('image.png', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

/home/yanzu/map/maplibre-native/platform/node/a.js:30
callback(err, { data: data });
^

TypeError: callback is not a function

May I ask how to solve it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your problem appears to be nothing to do with maplibre, but rather with the call to `fs.readFile`. On line 11 (of the posted code, or line 30 according to the error message) you're trying to call a function called `callback`, but you don't seem to have defined that function anywhere.